# how to disable a link created by another link by jquery (jsfiddle included)

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

i have a link when clicked it creates a div with another link inside it i want to disable the new link tried many solutions like preventDefault and return false but didn't work and here's the example http://jsfiddle.net/2RSJj/1/:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a[title='go']").click(function(e){
    $(".cities").append("<div class='city'><a href='http://www.google.com' class='mylink'>google</aiv>"); 
    e.preventDefault();
});

$(".cities .city a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).attr("class"));
});

});
```

main html :

```
<a href="#" title="go">go</a><p>
<div class="cities">

</div>
```

Comment: `</aiv>` is, presumably, a typo (of `</a></div>`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the link is dynamically added, you should use the `on()` method (assuming jQuery >= 1.7; jQuery < 1.7 should use `delegate()`) to prevent the default action of said link:

```
$('.cities').on('click', 'a.mylink', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2RSJj/3/).

The problem you were having is that the link isn't present when the event-binding happens, therefore the `click()` method doesn't bind the `click` event to the relevant `a` element. With `on()`, the `click` is attached to a parent/ancestor element (that exists at the point of event-binding), and then listens for that event (the `'click'` string in the first argument) being fired on an element that matches the selector (passed as the second argument).

Assuming that both the event and the selector match (the `a.mylink` element is `click`-ed), then the function is executed, which in this case simply prevents the default action being fired. It is, though, important to note that with delegated events you *cannot* simply `return false`, because the event has, by definition, already been fired by the time it's propagated/bubbled up to the ancestor element to which the event is bound.

Also, if an element between the two elements has an event handler that explicitly implements `return false` then the event delegation won't progress past that element (since the `click` will propagate/bubble to the element with the handler, which will respond with the `return false` (a combination of `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()`).

For example, in the following code, I'm using the `html`:

```
<a href="#" title="go">go</a><p>
<div class="cities">
    <div class="demo">
    </div>
</div>
```

In this case the `on()` method remains attached to the `.cities` element, but the `.demo` element has a click-handler which simply, as you might imagine, returns `false`:

```
$("a[title='go']").click(function(e){
    $(".demo").append("<div class='city'><a href='http://www.google.com' class='mylink'>google</a></div>"); 
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('.cities').on('click', 'a.mylink', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // using an alert because a simple 'e.preventDefault()` wouldn't
    // be visibly different to the 'return false'
    alert(e.type + ' event reached the ".cities" element!');
});

$('.demo').click(function(e){
    return false;
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2RSJj/5/).

In the above note that there is no alert fired when clicking the `a.mylink` element, whereas without that `click`-handler intercepting (and negating) the `click` event, the `alert()` *is* fired:

```
$("a[title='go']").click(function(e){
    $(".demo").append("<div class='city'><a href='http://www.google.com' class='mylink'>google</a></div>"); 
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('.cities').on('click', 'a.mylink', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(e.type + ' event reached the ".cities" element!');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2RSJj/6/).

So, be aware of those events bound to your elements when using delegation. It *can* be tricky (ish), when starting.

Reference:

- [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Oh, you're very welcome, I'm glad to have *been* of help! Thank *you* for the acceptance! =)